# how to match a pattern and add a character to it

Tags: python, regex

I have something like:

```
GCF_002904975:2.6672e-05):2.6672e-05.
```

and I would like to add the word '_S' right after any GCF(any number) entry before the next colon.

In other words I would like my text becoming like:

```
GCF_002904975_S:2.6672e-05):2.6672e-05.
```

I have repeated pattern like that all along my text.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: @Mariano, is there any way you can provide a shorter example; it's hard to follow given the length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily done with `re.sub` function. A working example would look like this:

```
import re

inp_string='(((GCF_001297375:2.6671e-05,GCF_002904975:2.6672e-05)0.924:0.060046136,(GCF_000144955:0.036474926,((GCF_001681075:0.017937143,...'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    outp_string = re.sub(r'GCF_(?P<gfc_number>\d+)\:', r'GCF_\g<gfc_number>_S:', inp_string)
    print(outp_string)
```

This code gives the following result, which is hopefully what you need:

`(((GCF_001297375_S:2.6671e-05,GCF_002904975_S:2.6672e-05)0.924:0.060046136,(GCF_000144955_S:0.036474926,((GCF_001681075_S:0.017937143,...`

For more info take a look at the docs:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions with a function substitution.  The solution below depends on the numbers always being 9 digits, but could be modified to work with other cases.

```
test_str = '(((GCF_001297375:2.6671e-05,GCF_002904975:2.6672e-05)0.924:0.060046136,GCF_000144955:0.036474926,((GCF_001681075:0.017937143,...'
new_str = re.sub(r"GCF_\d{9}", lambda x: x.group(0) + "_S", test_str)

print(new_str)
#(((GCF_001297375_S:2.6671e-05,GCF_002904975_S:2.6672e-05)0.924:0.060046136,GCF_000144955_S:0.036474926,((GCF_001681075_S:0.017937143,...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do a replace? Shortening your example string to make it easier to read:

```
"(((GCF_001297375:2.6671e-05,GCF_002904975:2.6672e-05)...".replace(":","_S:")
```